# How to implement item touches on SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-view, touch-event

I'm developing an android game with the standard pattern of SurfaceView, SurfaceHolder, Canvas, etc. In this game I will be drawing multiple bitmaps on the canvas that I would like to know if they've been touched. I am aware that I can override onTouchEvent() for SurfaceView and could linearly walk through all my items to determine if the touch coordinates contains the area of one of my bitmaps, but I was wondering if I could make things easier on myself.

Here's my question:
Can I have classes which handle drawing my bitmaps on the screen descend from android.View, attach them to my SurfaceView and register click listeners on them so I don't have to go through the process of determining clicks myself? Will the click listeners be accurate if I am drawing the views (bitmaps) to the canvas myself?

Furthermore, would I suffer a performance hit from making all of my bitmaps android views by bogging down the android view hierarchy and making android do the work I didn't want to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach normal android views to SurfaceView then what is the point in using SurfaceView! You are given a SurfaceView so that you can draw on the surface yourself rather than having the android view system do it for you. So "you" have to keep track of your touches by yourself.

You can refer to AOSP Gallery2 code which is purely OpenGL based and incorporate its design on handling touches.